# .htaccess: Redirect depending on accessed url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to, in my .htaccess, redirect the user to another url depending on what the user accesses.

In this case, http://example.com/awesome.com and http://awesome.com is the same site, and if the user is accessing http://example.com/awesome.com, I want him or her to be redirected to http://awesome.com.

Is this feasible?

Edit: With the help of answers, I came up with this working solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^awesome.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://awesome.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mod_rewrite (apache2 module)

this is the .htaccess that i use in order to redirect from my old domain to my new one (while keeping the link strcture e.g www.domain1.com/link/linkb.html becomes www.domain1.**gr**/link/linkb.html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain1.gr%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

google mod_rewrite for more information (syntax etc)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. However, I can't get it to work. See edit.

Comment: do you get the "internal server error" page? or it simply doesnt work?

Comment: It simply doesn't work. Can I, in my .htaccess, check if mod_rewrite is activated?

Comment: my guess is that mod_rewrite is not enabled. check your apache2 config file. then restart apache2. i dont know of a way to check this from the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about .htaccess, but you could just use server code on your 404 page to redirect them appropriately; this way you could collect stats, setup a toolbar, or whatever other actions you might want to take.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is about authorization, not redirection.  I recommend you look at the redirection support for Apache (or whatever web server you're using), which is a much better fit for this problem and just make sure your .htaccess/authorization is in line with the target.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^awesome\.example(/.*)?$ http://www.awesome.example$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Ben Galler: Oh wait, the group should be optional.

Comment: Can't get that to work either. According to my web hotel, mod_rewrite should be enabled...

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? http://www.awesome.example looks suspicious imo

Comment: @Ben Galler: Well, *awesome.example* is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Redirect & RedirectMatch options in apache. For simple cases, like yours it's simplier than a mod_rewrite.

```
Redirect /awesome.com http://ww.awesome.com
```

or

```
 Redirect permanent /awesome.com http://ww.awesome.com
```

Now, if example.com and awesome.com  are on the same apache server and same virtualhost you're maybe mising the named bases virtualhost things and you're maybe trying to make something really more complex than a simple named base virtualhost definition.